# CodeIgniter DataMapper - where_join_field Generating Incorrect Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-datamapper

My program is using the WanWizard DataMapper ORM with CodeIgniter, and needs to perform a simple query based on a field in a join table.  Here is my code:

```
$d = new Deal();

$deals = $d
    ->where_join_field('networks', 'status', 'active')
    ->get();
```

Fairly straightforward, as you can see.  A many-to-many relationship between "deals" and "networks", with a "status" field in the join table.  However, this is the query it generates:

```
SELECT * FROM (`deal`) WHERE `deal_network`.`status` = 'active'
```

Obviously, this doesn't work at all, because there in no `JOIN` in place to introduce the `deal_network` table.  I tried using `include_related`, but it aliases the `deal_network` table as `networks_deal_network`, resulting in an incorrect table reference.  How can I get DataMapper to `JOIN` that table into the query properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is table name bug in `_join_field` in `libraries/datamapper.php`.  I forked and submitted a pull-request with the fix.

https://bitbucket.org/jonahbron/datamapper